# Effective handling of text for syntax coloring

Tags: javafx-8

I'm making a text editor with syntax highlighting. Currenty the editable text is implemented as a list of HBoxes as lines, which hold lists of Text instances each holding a single word. This way I can change style of every word.

Apparently, this is wrong approach, because when the text files are big, my parser creates a load of Text instances which consumes a lot of memory (checked by MAT) and reduces the responsiveness of the program. Is there a better approach to implement text with syntax coloring?

Edit: seems like rendering text nodes is faster on Windows than on my Linux system. So graphics driver issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you try to merge `Text` objects which are similar coloured to reduce the amount of needed `Text` objects?
E.g. for the start method

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
}
```

you could merge `public void` to one text object and `start(` `Stage` `primaryStage){` to another.

For attribute declaration such as

```
@FXML Label lbl_name, lbl_amount, lbl_categories, lbl_date, lbl_value;
@FXML TextField tf_name;
@FXML ListView<String> lv_categories, lv_brand;
@FXML Spinner sp_amount, sp_value;
@FXML DatePicker dp_date;
```

you could use for `@FXML` a `Label`, in which each `@FXML` is seperated via the escape sequence`\n`to display multiple lines. The same is applicable for the object type declarations, which also should be coloured the same way.
E.g. `lbl_name, lbl_amount, lbl_categories, lbl_date, lbl_value;` could be merged together.

Another approach would be to only instantiate the lines which are actually shown to the user.

If you would parse the code which you  would like to show into HTML, you could also use the `HTMLEditor` in combination with HTML tags to highlight your syntax.